# Div layout issues - cannot get header to scale up/down with page

Tags: html, css

I'm currently designing a simple web app to be used by a variety of users with screen sizes of 1024x768 to 1600x1200 monitors.

This is what I've accomplished so far: http://jsfiddle.net/AdyQ5/

Unfortunately the top segment of the page seems to overflow into the body. Any idea on how I can fix this?

Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    min-height: 20%;
    max-height: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    min-height: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: none;
    top: 20%;
}
#text_header {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#title, #message {
    width: 95%;
}
.container {
    padding: 10px;
}
label {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="container"> 
  <span id="text_header">Virtual Idea Wall</span> 
    <p>
        <label for="title">Please give your idea a title</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="message">Please provide details of your idea</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="message" name="message"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="sendmessage">
    </p>
    </input>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="chat"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about your problem? I don't see anything amiss. Perhaps a screenshot of what it looks like in your browser.

Comment: What do you mean it overflows into the body?  If you're talking about word wrapping, you could make it not wrap and just hide it by using `overflow:hidden`, or make it scroll using `overflow:scroll`.  They might only work if you specify the `max-height` attribute though.

Comment: I think he means that in the JSFiddle, the header portion appears to contain the first textbox as well; there is a thin gray line between the textboxes. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply remove or adjust the default margins on the `<p>` tags.

```
p { margin:0; }
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/AdyQ5/2/)

To truly be dynamic you need to remove all the height attributes from the header:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
```

[Additional demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/AdyQ5/4/)

Comment: How is this different except reducing the spacing between the header and the content?

Comment: It doesn't extend the header content past it's container. If you can't see the bottom border of the header... calibrate your monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) (RWD) and use/modify some of the existing solutions out there like [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/), [Gumby](http://gumbyframework.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) (to name some of the better known).

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your css but you will have to limit the content in the header div.

```
#header {
width: 100%;
height: 20%;
position: fixed;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
top: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#main {
width: 100%;
height: 80%;
position: fixed;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: none;
top: 20%;
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdyQ5/5/)

Answer (score 0):

If your header is trying to contain the two text boxes, which it looks like it is, it's not big enough.  Since you didn't specify an `overflow` for the header, it simply overflows it into the main area.

A way to fix this would be to increase the size of the header, or specify an overflow for the header in case it's too small.

Here's an updated Fiddle in the case you wanted the header to `overflow:hidden`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rysparks/VKhqJ/)

Please understand that you never told CSS what do do with the header if there's too much inside of it.  So it defaulted.  If you want the text boxes to be a part of the main, you might have accidentally placed them inside of the header.